# Remote execution of a file is not working

Tags: bash, ssh, ksh

I'm trying to execute a local file (here `/tmp/cmd`) on a remote machine (slc05bkt) using SSH. Here's the command I'm trying from a script file:

```
cmd="ssh -v ssuthari@slc05bkt \"bash -l -s\" < /tmp/cmd"
$cmd
```

It's giving me the following exception:

```
ksh: line 1: /tmp/cmd: cannot open [No such file or directory]
```

Even after I added a copy of this local file to remote machine in the same location, it's giving me one more error :

```
ksh: line 1: bash -l -s: not found
```

The irony here is I'm able to execute the command directly on command line, but I'm unable to execute above lines from the script. Can someone please help me out on solving this issue?

Comment: what is the content of the file you copy to remote location ?

Comment: Don't put commands in variables.

Comment: @Archemar- The file I'm passing to SSH i.e. /tmp/cmd here contains the command i want to execute on remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

`$cmd` does not evaluate your variable, it just expands it and passes to the shell as a string, this is why you are getting errors.  In your case, try `eval "$cmd"`.

And in any case, I'd suggest to use `$(ssh the_rest_of_your_command_line)` instead of `eval "$cmd"`, since `eval` is a bad habit.

Comment: Even with $(ssh rest_of_command_line) is giving me the above errors.With eval,its working.Can you tell me why using eval is a bad habit?

Comment: Well, to investigate why $(ssh …) is failing I need to see the context.  eval() is bad since it executes anything you feed it, so it's a possibility to run something you didn't exepect.

Comment: @galaxy-- I'm trying the following code :   execCmd() { HOST=$1  IS_SCRIPT=$2  cmd="-v $USER@$HOST \"bash -l -s\" < $3"  $(ssh $cmd) }  execCmd "slc05bkt" "true" /tmp/cmd2  The file '/tmp/cmd2' is a local file which has the command to be executed on the remote machine slc05bkt.

Comment: As per my answer, the $cmd variable is going to be just expanded, so the redirection won't be performed.  It will work if you remove the redirection from the variable and add it at the end of the $().  Additionally to this $() is expected to be assigned to a variable to catch output.  Your whole script you presented here could be redefined to `execCmd(){cat "$3" | ssh -v $USER${USER:+@}${1:-localhost} } ; execCmd "slc05bkt" "true" /tmp/cmd2`